# Display mysql SUM in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum, inner-join

I am trying to output a MySQL query in PHP, previously I have been using this statement to print `echo("<td>$line[meal_name]</td></tr>");`
In my code below I try to do it this way but I am getting errors and I am struggling to find out why

```
$query = 'SELECT SUM(meal.calorific_output), SUM(activity.calorific_output)
                            FROM meal
                            INNER JOIN activity
                            ON meal.customer_id=activity.customer_id AND meal.day=activity.day
                            WHERE meal.customer_id =
                "'. $_POST['customer_id'] .'"AND meal.day = "'. $day.'"';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

            // Printing results
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo"<tr><td>$day</td>";
                echo("<td>$line[SUM(meal.calorific_output)]</td>");
                                echo("<td>$line[SUM(meal.calorific_output)]</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a name for your columns?  like `SELECT SUM(meal.calorific_output) as sumMeal,`

```
    $query = 'SELECT SUM(meal.calorific_output) as sumMeal, SUM(activity.calorific_output) as sumActivity
                            FROM meal
                            INNER JOIN activity
                            ON meal.customer_id=activity.customer_id AND meal.day=activity.day
                            WHERE meal.customer_id =
                "'. $_POST['customer_id'] .'"AND meal.day = "'. $day.'"';
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

            // Printing results
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo"<tr><td>$day</td>";
                echo("<td>$line["sumMeal"]</td>");
                                echo("<td>$line["sumActivity"]</td></tr>");
```